# Converting permutation to inversion representation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, permutation, inversion

Permutation `P = [a1, a2, ... , aN]` of the first `N` natural numbers can be represented by a list of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) `I = [i1, i2, ... , iN]`, where `iK` tells us how many numbers that are greater than `K` can be found before `K` in the permutation `P`.

Example: if `P = [3, 1, 4, 2]`, then `I = [1, 2, 0, 0]` (3 is placed 1, 3 and 4 are placed before 2, whereas 3 and 4 are not preceded by any bigger number).

There is an obvious algorithm that converts a permutation from standard to inversion form and runs in `O(N^2)` (we just follow the definition and count). The same holds for the inverse conversion (which is slightly less straight forward).

> Is there an algorithm that has lower time complexity?

Comment: I think it's possible using a Fenwick tree or similar data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple iterative dynamic-programming algorithm to solve this: for all i from 1 to `n` (length of the permutation) take the number `i` and look how many elements in `P` left of `i` have already been seen. Since we process `i` in increasing order, we know that the elements *not* seen are the elements bigger than `i` - and so we count and write down the number of those elements. The trick is to introduce an external list than keeps track of which elements in `P` have already been seen.

For the start, lets look at how to do it in `O(n^2)` way. For example, if `P=[4, 3, 2, 1]`, then the algorithm would executed as follows:

1. Create a structure `tree` initialized to zeros. It holds "1" in position `j` if element with j-th position in `P` has already been seen by the iterative algorithm.
2. Take 1, determine that `pos==3`. Write "1" down in the `tree[pos]`. Calculate `num_seen=sum(tree[0:3])` which is equal to 0. Write down `pos - num_seen + 1` at `I[0]`. After this: `tree = [0, 0, 0, 1], I = [3, 0, 0, 0]`
3. Take 2, write "1" down in the tree[1] and 1 at I[1]. `tree = [0, 1, 0, 1], I=[3,1,0,0]`.
4. Take 3, write "1" down in the tree[2] and 0 at I[2]. `tree = [0, 1, 1, 1], I=[3,1,0,0]`.
5. Take 4, write "1" down in the tree[0] and 0 at I[3]. `tree = [1, 1, 1, 1], I=[3,1,0,0]`.

The second trick is to use an efficient data structure to count the number of the seen elements in `O(n log n)` time instead of `O(n^2)` as above.

Here is Python code that uses a Fenwick tree to count the number of seen elements in a fast way:

```
def ft_sum(tree, a, b):
  if a == 0:
      s = 0;
      while  b >= 0:
          s += tree[b];
          b = (b & (b + 1)) - 1
      return s
  return ft_sum(tree, 0, b) - ft_sum(tree, 0, a - 1)

def ft_adjust(tree, k, v):
    while k < len(tree):
        tree[k] += v
        k |= k + 1

def calcI(P):
    n = len(P)
    tree = [0] * n
    I = [0] * n
    positions = [0] * n
    for i in xrange(n):
        positions[P[i]-1] = i
    tree = [0] * n
    for i in xrange(n):
        pos = positions[i]
        ft_adjust(tree, pos, 1)
        num_seen = ft_sum(tree, 0, pos)
        I[i] = pos - num_seen + 1
    return I
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I appreciate the real code (not just pseudo), also. For its completeness, I will accept your answer instead of mine:)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have found a simple solution, regarding pseudo-code, which works in `O(n log n)`, also.

```
initialize AVL-tree T
initialize array I of length n
for i = 1, 2, ... , n:
    I[P[i]] = T.countGreaterThan(P[i])
    T.add(P[i])
```